# What would happen if a same file being read and appended at the same time(python programming)?

Tags: python, multithreading, file-io, operating-system

I'm writing a script using two separate thread one doing file reading operation and the other doing appending, both threads run fairly frequently.

My question is, if one thread happens to read the file while the other is just in the middle of appending strings such as "This is a test" into this file, what would happen?

I know if you are appending a **smaller-than-buffer** string, no matter how frequently you read the file in other threads, there would never be incomplete line such as "This i" appearing in your read file, I mean the os would either do: append "This is a test" -> read info from the file; or: read info from the file -> append "This is a test" to the file; and such would never happen: append "This i" -> read info from the file -> append "s a test".

But if "This is a test" is big enough(assuming it's a **bigger-than-buffer string**), the os can't do appending job in one operation, so the appending job would be divided into two: first append "This i" to the file, then append "s a test", so in this kind of situation if I happen to read the file in the middle of the whole appending operation, would I get such result: append "This i" -> read info from the file -> append "s a test", which means I might read a file that includes an incomplete string?

Comment: "The GIL is always released when doing I/O."  http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock So I suppose you will.

Comment: It probably also partly depends on how atomic the OS file operations are. But you should probably assume that you might get an incomplete read back in this situation.

Comment: @Lennart: Actually I'm about to change my code using threading.RLock to make sure such thing never happens, just curious how "small" the os I/O operations can be and what would happen if you do read and append at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about this, just have your consumer look for a special character (endline would work) so that it knows that there wasn't an incomplete write.  So your producer (the one writing data to the file) can output partial data but the consumer (one reading from the file) will know it only got a partial write.

Is there a reason you're not using a PIPE instead of a file?  And is there a reason you're using threading?  You don't really gain anything except for maybe simplicity in coding but IMO you may as well have separate processes, then you can get a gain from this model.

Added: Unfortunately this I/O stuff is not just how Python handles things but how the OS handles things.  Everything you've said about worrying about the buffer is true.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

I would try to figure out what your buffer size is and for that I don't know even how to check.  I'm using OSX anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Well, as I said in my last comment, there are solutions to make sure you don't get a partial file, but out of curiosity I just want to know how the os/python would deal with this kind of situation.